# Apache Flink: Watermark does not progress with Broadcast stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

There is 1 high throughput Kafka stream defined as follows

```
val stream: DataStream[A] = flinkEnv
  .addSource(kafkaStreamSource)
  .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
     WatermarkStrategy
        .forBoundedOutOfOrderness[A](Duration.ofSeconds(0))
        .withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .withTimestampAssigner(new SerializableTimestampAssigner[A] {
            override def extractTimestamp(element: A, recordTimestamp: Long): Long = {
                element.lastUpdatedAt
              }
            }
        )
  )
  .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
  .reduce(.......)
```

The watermark for the above window operator forwards properly.

The `DataStream[A]` from the above window operator need to be enriched with some info kept in some S3 files. The S3 files updates very rarely.

S3 file is read as a stream and then broadcasted to enrich the elements from `DataStream[A]`.

```
 val textInputFormat = new TextInputFormat(new Path("s3 path...."))
 val enrichWithElements: BroadcastStream[EnrichWithElement] = flinkEnv.readFile(textInputFormat, "s3 path ...", FileProcessingMode.PROCESS_CONTINUOUSLY, 30)
    .map(s3Element => {
      EnrichWithElement(.....)
    })
    .broadcast(new MapStateDescriptor......)
```

The 2 streams are then connected to enrich all elements of type `A` with elements of type `EnrichWithElement`.

```
class EnrichedAProcess
    extends BroadcastProcessFunction[A,EnrichWithElement,EnrichedAElement] {
  override def processElement(
      value: A,
      ctx: Context,
      out: Collector[EnrichedAElement]): Unit = {
      .....
      out.collect(EnrichedAElement(....))
  }

  override def processBroadcastElement(
      value: EnrichWithElement,
      ctx: Context,
      out: Collector[EnrichedAElement]): Unit = {
      .........
  }
}
stream
  .connect(enrichWithElements)
  .process(new EnrichedAProcess)
```

The `EnrichedAProcess` has 2 inputs. One of them is constantly forwarding the watermark but the broadcasted stream does not have any time info or the watermark. This leads to the `EnrichedAProcess's` watermark not forwarding at all since one of its inputs is not passing in the watermark.

Is there a way to specify that `EnrichedAProcess's` watermark be only dependent on non broadcasted input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operator with multiple input channels sets its own watermark to the minimum of the latest watermarks received from all active channels.

What you can do is to apply a WatermarkStrategy to the broadcast stream that always returns MAX_WATERMARK as its watermark. (You don't need to worry about assigning timestamps for that stream.)

Comment: how would you do this with a kafka source?

Comment: The same way you would apply any other WatermarkStrategy to a KafkaSource.